# How to get difference between current date and given date from cell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA. I want to get the difference between current date and given date from user. How can I solve this? [image]When I click the Calculate point Button it showed #NAME?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Sum_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("F6:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDiff(""y"", Now, c6)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Datediff is a vba fonction, not an excel function. Use `Range("F6:F" & LastRow).Formula = "= Now-c6"` instead

Comment: I have tried this. But it gave 10146 instead of 27. How can I solve this?

Comment: which value do you have in cell C6 ?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range("F6:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=Text(Now()-C6, "y")"` should do it.

Refer to the [text function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) for other formatting options.

In particular:

[image: Image from the supplied link to support.office.com]

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind that if you want the difference between `Now` and some date in the future, you have to put the future date first to avoid less interesting results. In this regard, `DateDif` is a stronger option, and you'll avoid having to wrap it with `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the difference in years you can use DateDif

```
Range("F6:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(c6, Today(), ""y"")"
```

Comment: I want to add another date difference with this. How can I do this?
I have tried this:
 
Range("F6:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(c6, Today(), ""y"")+DateDif(E6, Today(), ""y"")"

But didn't work. What things should I do?

Comment: The phrase "didn't work" doesn't really tell us anything at all. What happened? What benefit do you gain from adding the two year values together?

Comment: Are you sure both the cells contain valid dates, and that they are both earlier than today's date?